# What does "should" mean in "I should get my assignment finished…"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, modal-verbs

> I **should** get my assignment finished this weekend if I have enough time.

The modal verb *should* has at least 7 meanings according to [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should). What does **should** mean in the quoted sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The closest definition for this scenario would probably be:

> —used in auxiliary function to express obligation, propriety, or expediency

It essentially means:

> I have a duty to get my assignment finished this weekend if I have enough time.

although it does not carry a stern connotation like the word "duty" does. You could also argue that it means something similar to:

> It would be a good idea to get my assignment finished this weekend if I have enough time.

Comment: Great answer. I believe it could also mean that the event is likely to occur. The meaning is ambiguous in this case. If you like, feel free to add this additional possibility to your own answer. Otherwise I can create an alternate answer.

Comment: @Tashus I disagree; in this context, he is not saying that it is likely that he will do his homework if he has time. He is saying that it is something that he must do. You could argue that "if he is saying he should do it, then it's likely that he will do it", but that meaning of "should" is usually found in probability situations, like "If there are 8 blue balls and 2 red balls, I should be able to draw a blue ball within two attempts."

Comment: That is a valid interpretation. I will offer an alternate answer. Welcome to ELL!

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "should" in the sentence is somewhat **ambiguous**. Depending on the context, it could be suggesting either **obligation or likelihood**.

An example of **obligation**:

> A: Is there anything that you have to do this weekend?
>
> B: I should get my assignment finished this weekend if I have enough time.

as in

> B: It would be prudent of me to finish my assignment.

An example of **likelihood**:

> A: Will you still be working on your assignment next week?
>
> B: I should get my assignment finished this weekend if I have enough time.

as in

> B: I expect to complete my assignment by the end of this weekend.